# The name 'Document' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In cshtml file i have the following code for example:

```
@inherits DocumentView<RegDoc, RegModel>

@{
Layout = "_layout.cshtml";

var document = Document;
}
```

Build succeeded... Also i can "Go To definition" from Document object to parent class. But when I try to run website I'm getting the Compilation Error :

> The name 'Document' does not exist in the current context

Could you please give some advice?

Comment: Do you mean `Model.Document`?

Comment: Is Document the name of the class? Then if you declare an object it should be: var document = new Document(); Or is the Model of type of Document then it should be: var document = Model;

Comment: Document is name of generic prop of parent class... public Tdoc Document { get { return _help.Value.Document; } }